# JMeter : How to test a REST "GET" Service that has both Query Parameters and Authentication info

Tags: jmeter

I tried the below approach for testing REST "Get" Service in JMeter. This service accepts the Authentication data (User Name and Password) and a Query Parameters.

1) Created a HTTP Request Sampler and defined 'Server Name', 'path', 'port' and Query Parameters'   (under send parameters with Request) section.
2) Created HTTP Authorization Manager and defined the User name and Password values.

Do not get the response, but when I try the same Request in Chrome plug in like (PostMan) I get the desired out put.

Can anyone please help me and let me know what could be the issue or I am missing any thing here.

Thanks in advance

-Balaji

Comment: hey add headermanager and pass all the related pairs

Answer (score 0):

Is your setup like the one shown in the image below ?

[image: REST Web-Service]